Swift Scheduled Notifications stop working after a few days, even if I reschedule them
I have a app where users can create routines. These routines can be set to days of the week. Due to the nature of the app, I hit the 64 notification limit quickly. So instead I just check the day of the week and schedule routines that match that day. I delete all pending notifications for cleanup (maybe not needed?), and reschedule anything that matches that day. This is done when routine settings are changed, routines are added, or when app enter foreground. This all works for multiple days in a row. After about a week or so though notifications stop getting scheduled. Due to the long time span its very hard to debug this problem.
class RoutineNotificationScheduler {
    
    static func rescheduleAllNotifications() {
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
          
          let routines = RoutinesGlobalsObject.shared.routineListArray
          let todayWeekday = Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: Date())
          
          routines.forEach { routine in
              if routine.daysOfWeek.contains(todayWeekday) {
                  scheduleNotification(for: routine)
              }
          }
      }
    private static func scheduleNotification(for routine: CreatedRoutine) {
        // Create the notification content object
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        // Set the sound for the notification from a custom file
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound(named: UNNotificationSoundName(rawValue: "\(routine.routineType).mp3"))
        // Set the title of the notification
        content.title = "Routine:"
        // Set the body of the notification, which is the name of the routine
        content.body = routine.name
        // Include custom data in the notification's userInfo dictionary
        content.userInfo = ["soundFilename": "\(routine.routineType).mp3"]

        // Use the Calendar to extract date components
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        // Create DateComponents to specify the time for the notification
        var dateComponents = DateComponents()
        // Extract the hour component from the routine's time and set it in dateComponents
        dateComponents.hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: routine.time)
        // Extract the minute component from the routine's time and set it in dateComponents
        dateComponents.minute = calendar.component(.minute, from: routine.time)

        // Create a trigger that defines when the notification should be delivered, without repeating
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: false)
        // Define a unique identifier for this notification using the routine name and the current weekday
        let identifier = "Routine_\(routine.name)_\(Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: Date()))"

        // Create a notification request with the identifier, content, and trigger
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        // Add the notification request to the system
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in
            // Check for errors in scheduling the notification
            if let error = error {
                print("Error scheduling notification: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }

I tried editing my routines to trigger the reschedule code. I tried adding new routines to see if they would work. They did not. I used LLDB to check the day of the week, and it came back correct.

One way forward could be that your static func takes a date as an argument instead of calling Date() inside the function. That way it might be easier to set up a test case that reproduces the issue. static func rescheduleAllNotifications(date: Date = .now)
